# Writing a blocking wrapper around twisted's IRC client

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I'm trying to write a dead-simple interface for an IRC library, like so:

```
import simpleirc

connection = simpleirc.Connect('irc.freenode.net', 6667)
channel = connection.join('foo')
find_command = re.compile(r'google ([a-z]+)').findall

for msg in channel:
    for t in find_command(msg):
        channel.say("http://google.com/search?q=%s" % t)
```

Working from [their example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#auto5), I'm running into trouble (code is a bit lengthy, so I pasted it [here](https://gist.github.com/e7e13f074a2691de6371)). Since the call to `channel.__next__` needs to be returned when the callback `<IRCClient instance>.privmsg` is called, there doesn't seem to be a clean option. Using exceptions or threads seems like the wrong thing here, is there a simpler (blocking?) way of using twisted that would make this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, if you're trying to use Twisted in a "blocking" way, you're going to run into a lot of difficulties, because that's neither the way it's intended to be used, nor the way in which most people use it.

Going with the flow is generally a lot easier, and in this case, that means embracing callbacks.  The callback-style solution to your question would look something like this:

```
import re
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.words.protocols import irc

find_command = re.compile(r'google ([a-z]+)').findall

class Googler(irc.IRCClient):
    def privmsg(self, user, channel, message):
        for text in find_command(message):
            self.say(channel, "http://google.com/search?q=%s" % (text,))

def connect():
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, Googler)
    return cc.connectTCP(host, port)

def run(proto):
    proto.join(channel)

def main():
    d = connect()
    d.addCallback(run)
    reactor.run()
```

This isn't absolutely required (but I strongly suggest you consider trying it).  One alternative is `inlineCallbacks`:

```
import re
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.words.protocols import irc

find_command = re.compile(r'google ([a-z]+)').findall

class Googler(irc.IRCClient):
    def privmsg(self, user, channel, message):
        for text in find_command(message):
            self.say(channel, "http://google.com/search?q=%s" % (text,))

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run():
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, Googler)
    proto = yield cc.connectTCP(host, port)
    proto.join(channel)

def main():
    run()
    reactor.run()
```

Notice no more `addCallbacks`.  It's been replaced by `yield` in a decorated generator function.  This could get even closer to what you asked for if you had a version of `Googler` with a different API (the one above should work with `IRCClient` from Twisted as it is written - though I didn't test it).  It would be entirely possible for `Googler.join` to return a `Channel` object of some sort, and for that `Channel` object to be iterable like this:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def run():
    cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, Googler)
    proto = yield cc.connectTCP(host, port)
    channel = proto.join(channel)
    for msg in channel:
        msg = yield msg
        for text in find_command(msg):
            channel.say("http://google.com/search?q=%s" % (text,))
```

It's only a matter of implementing this API on top of the ones already present.  Of course, the `yield` expressions are still there, and I don't know how much this will upset you. ;)

It's possible to go still further away from callbacks and make the context switches necessary for asynchronous operation to work completely invisible.  This is bad for the same reason it would be bad for sidewalks outside your house to be littered with invisible bear traps.  However, it's possible.  Using something like [corotwine](http://launchpad.net/corotwine), itself based on a third-party coroutine library for CPython, you can have the implementation of `Channel` do the context switching itself, rather than requiring the calling application code to do it.  The result might look something like:

```
from corotwine import protocol

def run():
    proto = Googler()
    transport = protocol.gConnectTCP(host, port)
    proto.makeConnection(transport)
    channel = proto.join(channel)
    for msg in channel:
        for text in find_command(msg):
            channel.say("http://google.com/search?q=%s" % (text,))
```

with an implementation of `Channel` that might look something like:

```
from corotwine import defer

class Channel(object):
    def __init__(self, ircClient, name):
        self.ircClient = ircClient
        self.name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            d = self.ircClient.getNextMessage(self.name)
            message = defer.blockOn(d)
            yield message
```

This in turn depends on a new `Googler` method, `getNextMessage`, which is a straightforward feature addition based on existing `IRCClient` callbacks:

```
from twisted.internet import defer

class Googler(irc.IRCClient):
    def connectionMade(self):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionMade(self)
        self._nextMessages = {}

    def getNextMessage(self, channel):
        if channel not in self._nextMessages:
            self._nextMessages[channel] = defer.DeferredQueue()
        return self._nextMessages[channel].get()

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, message):
        if channel not in self._nextMessages:
            self._nextMessages[channel] = defer.DeferredQueue()
        self._nextMessages[channel].put(message)
```

To run this, you create a new greenlet for the `run` function and switch to it, and then start the reactor.

```
from greenlet import greenlet

def main():
    greenlet(run).switch()
    reactor.run()
```

When `run` gets to its first asynchronous operation, it switches back to the reactor greenlet (which is the "main" greenlet in this case, but it doesn't really matter) to let the asynchronous operation complete.  When it completes, corotwine turns the callback into a greenlet switch back into `run`.  So `run` is granted the illusion of running straight through, like a "normal" synchronous program.  Keep in mind that it is just an illusion, though.

So, it's possible to get as far away from the callback-oriented style that is most commonly used with Twisted as you want.  It's not necessarily a good idea, though.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the extensive post! I can't seem to get the last example working - getting "AssertionError: Don't run gConnectTCP from the reactor greenlet". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think I'm confusing something about the third-to-last code quote: from where is the `run()` function supposed to be called?

Comment: I added another little code snippet and some text trying to explain it.  I hope this clears things up.

Comment: It did, thanks! New to both greenlet and twisted, so the hand-holding is very much appreciated. Thanks again!